# How can I repair Ubuntu after an aborted upgrade?

Tags: upgrade

I started the upgrade process from 17.04 to 17.10. But I received a call and had to do a job asap. I noticed the warning

> process cannot be aborted after all files have been downloaded

So I assumed it would be okay to kill the upgrade process during the download stage. But after restart, Ubuntu is stuck on the loading screen without any messages.

Comment: Are you *completely sure* that your system was downloading packages?  If so, then you system wasn't touched yet, and your problem is due to some other cause.

Comment: @user535733 not completly. There were decreasing timer, thus i assumed it is downloading stage. Also i canselled it in few minutes after start